# How to plot max latency in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, quarkus, metrics, micrometer

I'm using Quarkus framework with Micrometer as the metrics library. I have configured reporting timers with percentiles histogram for certain endpoints. In Grafana, I've created a dashboard to monitor latency using a 99th percentile query:

`sum by (app) (histogram_quantile(0.99, rate(timers_pcnt_myapi_seconds_bucket{app="myapp"}[2m])))`

Additionally, I would like to establish a line for the maximum latency. What is the correct approach to achieve this?"

metrics output example:

```
timers_pcnt_myapi_seconds_bucket{app="myapp",le="22.906492245",} 19557.0
timers_pcnt_myapi_seconds_bucket{app="myapp",le="28.633115306",} 19557.0
timers_pcnt_myapi_seconds_bucket{app="myapp",le="30.0",} 19557.0
timers_pcnt_myapi_seconds_bucket{app="myapp",le="+Inf",} 19557.0
timers_pcnt_myapi_seconds_count{app="myapp",} 19557.0
timers_pcnt_myapi_seconds_sum{app="myapp",} 453.418

# HELP timers_pcnt_myapi_seconds_max  
# TYPE timers_pcnt_myapi_seconds_max gauge
timers_pcnt_myapi_seconds_max{app="myapp",} 0.217
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate max from the histogram, it's the 100th percentile:

```
histogram_quantile(1.00, ...)
```

or you can do it without the histogram, Micrometer provides you a time-window max and Prometheus has a `max` function that you can use to aggregate:

```
timers_pcnt_myapi_seconds_max
```